# soapui free version assertions request = response

Tags: groovy, match, soapui, assertions

I will pass any memberid or active card for matching to verify activecard(cardno) matches memberid passed.
 Request:

```
 <MemberID>${Property Looper#memberid}</MemberID>
 <CardNo>${Property Looper#ActiveCard}</CardNo>
```

Expected result:

```
 <ReturnMessage>Cardno not found</ReturnMessage>
```

OR

```
 <ReturnMessage>SUCCESS</ReturnMessage>
```

How to put assertions to check if the member id in request will check matching with response? contains and not contains assertions seems like not working that well for this condition? 
and i want the test to be passed even if the matching failed as the ultimate goal is to make sure the error is not from the data (the test pass regardless the return status) but the application. 
 Thanks

Edit:
[after running the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzyX9.png)

Edit 2:
[after running script assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzyX9.png)
[custom property added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqBOL.png)

Comment: Is that the whole response or just part of it?

Comment: @Rao just part of it. it will show card info if it passes.

Comment: Please check the answer to see if that helps.

Comment: NewBieMandy, have you got chance to try the solution?

Comment: @Rao im still figuring out on the answer as i just start using this tool days ago. i got this error "assert actualMessage == expectedMessage | | | null | SUCCESS false" . i did add custom property

Comment: Have you run the step? Will you be able to show with a screen shot?

Comment: the error i mentioned is shown under `script assertion - FAILED` (no idea how to insert image). When i run the script, this is shown `INFO:Return message from response: null`. Am i doing the correct thing?

Comment: It seems that you did run the step. Please run the test step, automatically script assertion would run.

Comment: yes i did. it showed `script assertion - FAILED` `assert actualMessage == expectedMessage | | | null | SUCCESS false`

Comment: Can you share the screen shot? Add it in the question or google drive or GitHub and add link.

Comment: i added the screenshot in the question. Please have a look

Comment: How does the response look? Have you added test case level custom property? Show the screen shot of script assertion screen.

Comment: @Rao i have edited the question with the screenshots

Comment: Reporting different error in different instances. Can you check it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Script Assertion` to achieve the same.

Based on the description, the assertion should be able to handle both below cases :

- some case, you may expect `card not found`
- some case, you may expect `SUCCESS`

Define test case level custom property, say `EXPECTED_MESSAGE` and provide appropriate expected value depending on the case.

Add below script assertion for the SOAP Request test step.

```
//Check if the response is received
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Parse the response and find the ReturnMessage value
def actualMessage = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).'**'.find{it.name() == 'ReturnMessage'}?.text()
log.info "Return message from response: $actualMessage"

//Read the expected message from custom property
def expectedMessage = context.expand('${#TestCase#EXPECTED_MESSAGE}')

//Verify with actual value
assert actualMessage == expectedMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the output is like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>  
<ReturnMessage>SUCCESS</ReturnMessage>   
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

you can use the below script assertion

```
def groovyUtils = new  com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def response = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("First Step#Response")

String x = response.getNodeValue("//*[local-name()='ReturnMessage']")

 if(x.contains("Cardno not found" ) || x.contains("SUCCESS"))
 {
  log.info "Success"
 }
 else
{
log.info " Fail"
}
```

output is

```
Sat Oct 28 15:22:02 IST 2017:INFO:Success
```

Rao's approach is also correct. Its just that if you are following that approach you have to have 2 expected result custom properties since you have 2 properties.

You may have to use if condition before assertion as 1 assertion will fail because your results would be either "Cardno not found" or "SUCCESS"

2 Changes you might have to make in the script. replace 'First Step' with the name of your teststep

change the getNodeValue step to reach the actual place

Comment: def response = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("MemberID Matching#ResponseAsXML")
    String x = response.getNodeValue("//*:ReturnMessage")

Comment: i edited these two. i got error unexpected element CDATA

Comment: can you try the same way i did like                      
                     response.getNodeValue("//*[local-name()='ReturnMessage']")       i was able to make it work. for testing the above code.. you can paste the above code in any response and name the test step(not request) as "MemberID Matching" and put the above code in the next groovy step you will not get the CData error